# CGRectMake for the instance of a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I know it is not wise to show a `UIViewController` in another `UIViewController` but I don't know how else to do this.  I have a 3D view controller (`ThreeDViewController`) that shows a 3D object and allows the user to rotate and zoom in on the obect.  I would like to be able to make a small view of the `ThreeDViewController` that still allows interaction on my `SideBySideViewController`.

```
  self.ViewInstance = [[ThreeDViewController alloc]init];
  [self.view addSubview:self.ViewInstance.view];
```

That is what I have so far but it only imports the `UIViewController` so it takes up the whole screen, and I want a set size box of it.  And `initWithFrame` doesn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
float scaleFactor = 0.5;
    CGRect temp = CGRectMake(self.ViewInstance.view.frame.origin.x, self.ViewInstance.view.frame.origin.y,self.ViewInstance.view.frame.size.width*scaleFactor, self.ViewInstance.view.frame.size.height*scaleFactor);
    self.ViewInstance.view.frame = temp;
```